# Designing Integration event application

Tags: domain-driven-design, event-programming, integration, event-handling

We have a microservice that integrates with a third party system via REST API to handle appointment booking for our customer. It takes advantage of the event-driven model. Our microservice emits out an integration event called the AppointmentCreated event post-appointment booking with the third party service.

The **AppointmentCreated** event is handled in the processor, which notifies our internal(monolithic) system to do some POST appointment work.
Example processes we have in processor and the processor will go to the next step regardless these steps succeed or not, which was okay when we started this project

1. Notify the internal system that a customer booked an appointment
2. Update User consents based on whether they selected to be opt-in for SMS notification

Current **AppointmentCreated** C#

```
public class AppointmentCreated : IntegrationEvent
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset CreatedAt { get; set; }
        public string PatientName { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset StartTime { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset EndTime { get; set; }
        public bool SmsConsent { get; set; }
        public Guid? ContactKey { get; set; }
        public string PatientEmail { get; set; }
}
```

Now the business is asking to notify the SalesForce team via a REST API call once the appointment is booked in our microservice with what we send out in the REQUEST with the third party and the RESPONSE we get from the third party HTTP call. The business also wants to be notified whether we fail to notify SalesForce for any number of reason, which we can have some alerts set up on the event bus to do that.

Would it make sense to emit out a specific integration event from our microservice just to notify ThirdParty on our event bus and handle the REST API to notify SalesForce in the processor?
Emit two events after our microservice is able to book an appointment with the third party.

1. **AppointmentCreated**
2. **NotifySalesForceAppointmentCreated** only needs Request and Response data that we make the call to the third-party application to make an appointment. We only want this data on successful appointment booking. It doesn't care about the current **AppointmentCreated**
   content.

[image]

Do you guys have any suggestion or anything with this approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion there is only one event and it is **AppointmentCreated**.

On this event you can have different consumers(subscribers). One of this consumers can be dedicated consumer that has one job to notifying Sales Force.

The second event you have written **NotifySalesForceAppointmentCreated** is a command, not an event and in my opinion you don't need it.

Each consumer can hold separately execution / processing and decide if the consumer has reacted adequately on the event.

F.ex. Your NotifySalesForceAppointment in order to perform the notification to Sales Force needs to collect some data from external system via REST call.

1. You consumer reacts on the event, the processing starts you write it to some persistent storage.
2. You collect data from external systen via rest call, you write the data. (writing data is optional if things go wrong you can aways just go from the start)
3. You notify the SalesForce and write into the persistent store that the processing is complete.

If one of these steps fail you can begin from the start.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time out for responding. I do agree with you on there is only one event. The **NotifySalesForceAppointmentCreated** definitely sounds more like a command than an event for sure. The reason why I wouldn't want to just have one event is that SalesForce requires specific information which is not useful for the current consumer. I wouldn't be sending information on my event bus for a consumer who doesn't care about the information that SalesForce cares about and vice versa.

Comment: As I said you can have different consumers. Now you need to separate your execution state and processing state from your event. The event is one, it is AppointmentCreated. The state you point out is execution/processing state of one consumer. You sould not mix your state with your event.

Comment: I think what Alexander means is that you create a new event handler that is a second consumer of the AppointmentCreated event; the single responsibility of this event handler is to make a request to the SalesForce REST Api with only the data required for that call. If this REST call fails, you can handle that error with some notification.

Comment: Yes, I understand the approach of having two handlers to perform two district operations. I thought about this approach. What I really don't like is that I am having to modify the **AppointmentCreated** event to include the REQUEST and RESPONSE data that is needed to notify SalesForce. It may not be a big deal I guess to modify the existing event to include more data.

Comment: You don't need to modify the event. And you should not modify the event. Separate Event from execution/processing logic. These are two different things.

Comment: Then, I think I am confused about your previous comment about having one event and two consumers, each consumer processes distinct business rule. If you are purposing not to change the event then, what way I could deliver the new content requirement that I have to provider for SalesForce?

Comment: So you have your microservice and you have your internal service. And you need information from this internal service to be available for the notification to salesforce. One way would be your event has lets say an ID. Your first consumer will persiste the response from the internal service to some place with the ID of the event. Your second consumer will only notify Sales Force when the data from the internal system is present. You can set f.ex. a timeout if lets say response from internal service is not persisted withing Xms there is. problem.

Comment: Now this is just a rough example I can not code it for you. But basicly you should try separate the Event from the processing state, unless it is not the external system pushing the event that has included it. All this is very conditional but...I am not in your shoes after all :)

Comment: I think I made this a little confusing. The request and response data I need is in the microservice API. It is not present in the internal service. I'll update how many systems and at which point data is at.

Comment: Its not confusing. I think I have read you well from the start. Lets look it from another angle.  What do you think does not fit your use case from what I have written so far.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120214/discussion-between-user2884707bond-and-alexander-petrov).